# How can I debug an access violation which is raised whilst my application is initializing?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

My Delphi application raises an access violation error even **before running**. I made a break-point at `Application.Initialize` line, but my app doesn't run and I still get the exception. How can I find the issues?

Comment: try this tutorial on init/finalization debug. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOTAm1hivRg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [unit initialization section](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Programs_and_Units#The_Initialization_Section) is the code that runs before `Application.Initialize` executes. That's the code that is in the `initialization` sections at the bottom of a unit.

So you would appear to have an error in that code. Most likely it will be in one of your own units. The thing to do is to run under the debugger and see which unit the debugger breaks at. Make sure your IDE is configured to break when access violations occur.

[image]

I'd also recommend enabling Debug DCUs in case the exception surfaces in one of the RTL/VCL units.

Comment: Where is the `initialization` section exactly? I can't find it

Comment: It's at the bottom of a unit. Not all units have them. You'll have lots of them in your project. You need to work out where the exception is raised. That's the first task. Let the debugger do that. In an ideal world you'd have madExcept in your app and you'd get a bug report with a stack trace and lots of useful details. Without that, you'll have to do it the hard way.

Comment: Kermia: in case you weren't aware of it, you can run your program in the IDE to trace into each unit's initialization code using F7 to compile rather than F8. Then use F7 to single step through your program. The debugger will take you to the initialization code of each unit as it's run.  I *believe* that the order of the units in your .dpr uses statement controls the order unit initialization to some degree.